# Calling an observable function twice not work in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to import excel and I use SheetJS to do this.

```
  getSheet<T>(fileReader: FileReader, headers: string[], index: number): Observable<T[]> {
return new Observable((observer) => {

  fileReader.onload = ((ev: ProgressEvent): void => {
    let workbook;
   .......

    workbook = XLSX.read(binary, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellStyles: true });

    let getData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<T>(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[index]], { header: headers, range: 1 });

    observer.next(getData);

    observer.complete();
  })


});  }
```

In the other function, I call this observable function.

```
getExcel(evt: Event) {
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer((<any>evt.target).files[0]);

let getdataA$!: Observable<interfaceA[]>
let getdataB$!: Observable<interfaceB[]>
let getdataC$!: Observable<interfaceC[]>

getdataA$ = this.getSheet(fileReader, this.headerA, 0);

getdataB$ = this.getSheet(fileReader, this.headerB, 1);

getdataC$ = this.getSheet(fileReader, this.headerC, 2);

 const observable = forkJoin({
  getdataA$,
  getdataB$,
  getdataC$,
});

}
```

I use RxJS operators, like forkJoin,combineLatest

But it doesn't work..........

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you subscribe to the observable somewhere in your code ?

Comment: Yes, I did subscirbe the observable variable after forkJoin method. I used console.log to see the data.

Comment: fileReader.onload is an asynchronous function. Does it affect the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing variables outside the observable object that created is not good.

In this case, your `fileReader` is outside of `new Observable(() => ...)`, so the file my be load only once.

I think you have to create FileReader instance in `new Observable(() => ...)` so that every time you subscribe the observable object, a new FileReader instance will be created.

Simple sample code below:

```js
getSheet<T>(someFile: File, anotherArguments: any): Observable<T[]> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // create a new FileReader instance when every Observable has been created
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {
      observer.next();
      observer.complete();
    }

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(someFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, just read the whole file outside the `getSheet<T>`, then pass the binary into `getSheet<T>`.

Comment: You can also wrap the whole read file task into an observable, then switch to another observable to process the excel content.